# Move from a fragment with listview adapter to new activity base on each item selected

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity

I have done some series of research about how to make each item of the listview in fragment activity to move to another activity having getView() from swipeListadapter. The codes below contain the tab fragment containing the swipe listadapter for the list view and the setonitemclicklistener.

```
public class SwipeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieList;
    private String[] bgColors;


    public SwipeListAdapter(Activity tab1, List<Movie> movieList) {
        this.activity = tab1;
        this.movieList = movieList;
        bgColors = activity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movie_serial_bg);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieList.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_rows, null);

        TextView serial = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.serial);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        serial.setText(String.valueOf(movieList.get(position).id));
        title.setText(movieList.get(position).title);

        String color = bgColors[position % bgColors.length];
        serial.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

The code below is my fragment tab class

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment implements ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private int index;
    private int[] images = new int[] { R.drawable.gallery1, R.drawable.gallery2, R.drawable.gallery3, R.drawable.gallery4, R.drawable.gallery5, R.drawable.gallery6, R.drawable.gallery7, R.drawable.gallery8 };
    ImageSwitcher switcher;
    android.os.Handler Handler = new Handler();

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private SwipeListAdapter adapter;
    private List<Movie> movieList;
    private ListView listView;

   // private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";

    private String URL_TOP_250 = "http://192.177.53.152/locator/test/refractor.php?offset=";

    // initially offset will be 0, later will be updated while parsing the json
    private int offSet = 0;

    private static final String TAG = Tab1.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);


        listView = (ListView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list);

        listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

        movieList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new SwipeListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //getView().setOnClickListener();

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                                        fetchMovies();
                                    }
                                }
        );



        return vi;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {


                switch(position) {
                    case 1:
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), New1.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), New2.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    default:
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), New3.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                }


            }
        });


        switcher = (ImageSwitcher) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher1);
        switcher.setFactory(this);

        switcher.setImageResource(images[index]);
        switcher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                index++;
                if (index >= images.length) {
                    index = 0;
                }
                switcher.setImageResource(images[index]);
            }
        });
        switcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_in));
        switcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_out));

        //auto change image
        Handler.post(UpdateImage);

    }




    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        fetchMovies();
    }


    private void fetchMovies() {

        // showing refresh animation before making http call
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        // appending offset to url
        String url = URL_TOP_250 + offSet;

        // Volley's json array request object
        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        if (response.length() > 0) {

                            // looping through json and adding to movies list
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject movieObj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                    int rank = movieObj.getInt("rank");
                                    String title = movieObj.getString("postTitle");

                                    Movie m = new Movie(rank, title);

                                    movieList.add(0, m);

                                    // updating offset value to highest value
                                    if (rank >= offSet)
                                        offSet = rank;

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        // stopping swipe refresh
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server Error: " + error.getMessage());

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // stopping swipe refresh
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }


    Runnable UpdateImage = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Increment index
            index++;
            if (index > (images.length - 1)) {
                index = 0;
            }
            switcher.setImageResource(images[index]);
            // Set the execution after 5 seconds
            Handler.postDelayed(this, (3 * 1000));
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View makeView() {
        ImageView myView = new ImageView(getActivity());
        myView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        myView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(Gallery.LayoutParams.
                FILL_PARENT, Gallery.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        return myView;
    }

}
```

In a nutshell, whenever I click any of the item listview, the app crashes and system logcat is not giving any clue to that. I want to be able to click an item on the listview in d fragment and to be directed to a new activity. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the logcat crash output.